# Exposing function or transformation matrix that QGIS georeferencer develops to georeference raster?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

The problem:
Think of the London Tube Map.  Logically correct, but physically inaccurate.  I want to display such an arist's impression (un-transformed, so recognisable) on a mobile web site and have the phone's GPS accurately place the user on the logical map.  (The tube map is an example - it's not underground :))

I'm currently using CV2's homography functions to achieve this - given some source/destination co-ordinates it emits a transformation matrix which I can use in javascript to take a gps co-ordinate, transform it and display it on the picture.  This works well, but the QGIS georeferencer makes it so much easier to capture co-ordinates and check the result for accuracy, and I think that a gis is going to make a better job of mapping.

So I'd like to use QGIS for this job, but I can't see a way of grabbing the transformation matrix I assume is generated by the georeferencer.
Has anybody got any idea whether this is possible?